# how to Deserialize string into object in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, gson

how to  deserialize below string in android. I have tried below

```
String json= ls.get(j).getCwc();
Example example = new Gson().fromJson(json,Example.class);
```

**Json**

```
[{
  "company":"gjjzh",
  "AvgSal":"hjsj"
},
{
  "company":"hjd",
  "AvgSal":"hjd"
},
{
  "company":"hm",
  "AvgSal":"lk"
},
{
  "company":"er",
  "AvgSal":"io"
},
{
  "company":"uo",
  "AvgSal":"tr"
}]
```

Comment: why don't you automate it with retrofit or similar library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
String json= ls.get(j).getCwc();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Example>>(){}.getType();
List<Example> example = new Gson().fromJson(json,type);
```

where `Example` is

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("company")
@Expose
private String company;
@SerializedName("AvgSal")
@Expose
private String avgSal;

public String getCompany() {
return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
this.company = company;
}

public String getAvgSal() {
return avgSal;
}

public void setAvgSal(String avgSal) {
this.avgSal = avgSal;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a model class for the object.

Example.java

```
public class Example{
    String company = "";
    String AvgSal = "";
}
```

and then you need to write code as below to convert `JSONArray` string into `List<Model>`.

```
String json= ls.get(j).getCwc();
Type modelListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Example>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Example> modelList = new Gson().fromJson(json, modelListType);
```

This will convert `JSONArray` into `ArrayList`.